# mac terminal does not save bash colors

Tags: macos, bash, colors, terminal

Im still getting new to the terminal and editing bash files and my terminal used save its content and now every time I open a new terminal the colors are set back to the original. These were my commands.

```
 export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$ " 
 export CLICOLOR=1
 export LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxCxegedabagacad alias ls='ls -GFh'
```

Comment: Correct, commands you run are not saved between sessions. You need to put them in your session startup scripts (`.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` etc.) for that to work. `export` isn't necessary on `PS1` either for the record.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @EtanReisner, that seemed to work!